# Print rows and columns (openpypxl) python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

The following program prints all the individual values in the excel sheet top to bottom, left to right one at a time

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('DEMO.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
```

but I want to print even the value's row and column. Eg: If there are 3 rows filled in the excel sheet with "Apple", "Orange", "Grapes", then my output should be like:

1. Apple A1
2. Orange A2
3. Grapes A3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [docs for `Cell`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/cell/cell.html#Cell):

```
...
print(cell.value, cell.coordinate)
```